# CA Deployment with docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

*Hello! Help me please. How can i deploy CA to docker desktop with using docker-compose.yml with new port and operation port after modifying fabric-ca-server-config.yaml file? I try to do it and every time when i deploy my CA i receive default ports.*

```
fabric-ca-server:
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --config /mnt/b/TestFolderCAHFUpdate/testingDir/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml'
    container_name: fabric-ca-server
    environment:
    - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/mnt/b/TestFolderCAHFUpdate/testingDir/fabric-ca-server
    # - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca1
    - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/mnt/b/TestFolderCAHFUpdate/testingDir/ca-cert.pem
    - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/mnt/b/TestFolderCAHFUpdate/testingDir/msp/keystore/49ac52bedc38ece5b9f5bb61d8367b6dd65c3e4da6130e0718a62d2c6465505b_sk
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    ports:
    - 7054:7054
    volumes:
    - ./fabric-ca-server-config.yaml:/mnt/b/TestFolderCAHFUpdate/testingDir/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
```

Comment: Please share your code to help others to answer the question.

Comment: @AmitDash I share my docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set enviroment `FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT` value to port which you want use and modify port Mapping:

```
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=false
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/3adeeadd955deae62f8172aa013dfa7646350a7d36d85024796396eedda275e2_sk
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=9054
    ports:
      - "9054:9054"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. And how can I install listen address environment variable in this file?